# remove indent when bolding the beginning of paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, bold

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% -------- Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% \usepackage{fontspec}             
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}               % \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               
\usepackage{titlesec}                   
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{helvet}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt}
% -------------- margins
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.75in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.75in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.25in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.575in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

%-----------WATERMARK TEST 
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%--------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\LARGE Eduardo Flores Lomas
    }\par}

% ------------ Work Experience

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{L{14cm}R{2.7cm}}

\noindent\textbf{
 Farmacias del Ahorro
 }
 - \scriptsize{Largest retail pharmacy chain in Mexico (1,300+ stores)} & \scriptsize{Jan 15' - Current}
\\
 Data Science Coordinator
 - \scriptsize{Technology and Projects Department} 
 \\
 % \footnotesize{ 
 \multicolumn{2}{p{16.7cm}}{
 Responsible for finding and implementing data science methods to solve a wide range of business problems.
 }
```

But I want to avoid that ugly indentation at "Farmacias del Ahorro" when I bold it...

[image]

When I remove the `\textbf` at the beginning of "Farmacias del Ahorro" it aligns perfectly:

[image]

As can be seen, I've tried `\noindent` ... what am I missing?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have trailing whitespace somewhere (or missing a `%`). Change `\noindent\textbf{` to `\noindent\textbf{%`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer wow! that did it! Thanks!!

Comment: size changes do not take an argument so `\scriptsize{...}` should be `{\scriptsize ....\par}` otherwise the rest of teh document from that point is affected.

Answer (score 2):

The error was

```
\noindent\textbf{
 Farmacias del Ahorro
 }
```

causing a superfluous whitespace, so either add a `%` at the end of the line

```
\noindent\textbf{%
Farmacias del Ahorro
}
```

or put everything on two lines only:

```
\noindent\textbf{Farmacias del Ahorro 
}
```

Now, depending on the real usage, a `%` after `Ahorro` might be appropiate!